# Obtaining a value from a pandas dataframe using another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

```
DF1
key1    key2
aa       a1
bb       b1
cc       c1
dd       d1

DF2
name  a1   b1   c1   d1
all    0    0   0     0
jack   12   22  52    44
toby   11   45  21    44
```

for a given keyword lets say 'dd', i will first check in DF1['key1'] if 'dd' is present. If yes i will take corresponding value for DF1['key2'] and name it as key. Now what I need is find the value associated with Jack in DF2 in column name == key. I need a single python function taht executes all this. so the input arguments will be two dataframes, the keyword and the name,  and output will be a value.

for example:
input: DF1, DF2, jack, bb
output: 22

Dataframes can contain lower case, upper case and white spaces as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def fn(df1, df2, a, b):
    c = df1.loc[df1["key1"] == b, "key2"].tolist()[0]
    return df2.loc[df2["name"] == a, c].tolist()[0]


val = fn(df1, df2, "jack", "bb")
print(val)
```

Prints:

```
22
```

Comment: @KathanVyas Yes, if column `"a"` doesn't exist in `df2`, it throws exception.